# having trouble saying this in a rigorous way

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

This is part of a problem I am working on and I have most of it figured out, but there is this one little piece that's kind of bothering me.

I have a function $f:D \rightarrow R$ which is continuous. $f(0)= 0$ and $f'(0) < 0$

For the theorem I'm going to use later I need to lock down an endpoint to use below the x-axis.

I need to somehow say that because the derivative at x = 0 is less than zero, there is a point somewhere in the neighborhood of zero (only considering positive values of x here) such that the value of $f(x)$ is less than $0$.

I was going to try to use the epsilon-delta definition of limit but I got stuck.

$\rvert \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0} - f'(x_0) \lvert < \epsilon$

I figure I just have to pick some epsilon and then re-arrange this inequality to get that $f(x)$ is less than zero in this neighborhood, but I have trouble with the inequalities.

Thanks

Comment: One way is to go by contradiction. Suppose the negative of what you want to show, i.e. that $f(x)\ge0$ throughout some neighborhood of the form $[0,a\rangle$. Then the difference quotient is $f(x)/x$, quotient of a nonnegative by a positive, result being nonnegative. But nonnegative numbers can not have a negative limit $f'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we should be able to prove this by contradiction.  Suppose $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function such that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(0) < 0$.

Let's assume $D = \mathbb{R}$ for the sake of simplicity. Then given $\epsilon > 0$, suppose for all $y \in (0, \epsilon)$, $f(y) > 0$.

Since $f(0) = 0$, and $f(y) > 0$, then $\frac{f(y) - f(0)}{y - 0} = \frac{f(y)}{y} > 0$.

In particular, $\lim \limits_{ n \to \infty} \frac{f(0 + \frac{1}{n}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}} \geq 0$, since for each $n \geq N$ (where $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$), $\frac{f(0 + \frac{1}{n}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}} > 0$ by our assumption that $f(y) > 0$.

But $\lim \limits_{ n \to \infty} \frac{f(0 + \frac{1}{n}) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}  = f'(0)$, so we found that $f'(0) \geq 0$, which contradicts the assumption that $f'(0) < 0$.